# Reading created record type from file in pascal

Tags: types, record, pascal

I'll try to be the shortest possible.
I have these DATA TYPES in my program.'

```
type
  pha = (SenoraBlanco, SenorVerde, SenoraCeleste, ProfesorCiruela,
    SenoritaEscarlata, CoronelMostaza, Biblioteca, Cocina, Comedor, Estudio,
    Vestibulo, Salon, Invernadero, SalaDeBaile, SalaDeBillar, Candelabro,
    Cuchillo, Cuerda, LlaveInglesa, Revolver, Tubo);

  a = Candelabro..Tubo;
  h = Biblioteca..SalaDeBillar;
  p = SenoraBlanco..CoronelMostaza;

  sbr = record
    arma: a;
    habt: h;
    prj: p;
  end;

var
  game: text;
  sobre: sbr;
```

And I want to read this line from a file and then assign it to fields of the variable sobre, `type sbr`:

`CoronelMostaza Candelabro Vestibulo`

Essentially this is what I'm trying:

```
sobre.prj  := CoronelMostaza;
sobre.arma := Candelabro;
sobre.habt := Vestibulo;
```

And this is what I've tried so far:

```
ReadLn(game, sobre.prj, sobre,arma, sobre.habt);
```

I'd tried turning off the IO check with no result, the closest I've got to the answer of this problem is assign the first word to the first variable, but always end in either an error or empty variables. Please help me and if you will, give me an idea of what's happening behind all this!

Comment: The text file you are reading from, does it contain the ordinal values or the names of type `pha`? In this case `5 15 10` or `CoronelMostaza Candelabro Vestibulo`.

Comment: The text file contains the names in pha and some integers i have to read too. The names are also in subtypes p, h, a separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the text file contains the type literals of type `pha`.

Declare a a text constant containing those literals:

```
const
  phaStr : array[pha] of string = ('SenoraBlanco', 'SenorVerde', 'SenoraCeleste', 'ProfesorCiruela',
    'SenoritaEscarlata', 'CoronelMostaza', 'Biblioteca', 'Cocina', 'Comedor', 'Estudio',
    'Vestibulo', 'Salon', 'Invernadero', 'SalaDeBaile', 'SalaDeBillar', 'Candelabro',
    'Cuchillo', 'Cuerda', 'LlaveInglesa', 'Revolver', 'Tubo');
```

To get an integer index of one of those string literals:

```
function IndexOfPhaStr( const aStr : string) : integer;
var
  aPHA : pha;
begin
  Result := -1;
  for aPHA := Low(pha) to High(pha) do
  begin
    if (aStr = phaStr[aPHA]) then
    begin
      Result := Ord(aPHA);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The file contains text information, so you will have to translate the text into your data types.
A simple example using `TStringList` in `classesh.inc`:

```
var

  i : Integer;
  sList : TStringList;
  s : String;
  ix : array [1..3] of integer;
begin
  ...
  sList := TStringList.Create;
  sList.Delimiter := ' ';
  AssignFile(game,'TEST.Txt');
  Reset(game);
  System.ReadLn(game, s);
  System.CloseFile(game);
  sList.DelimitedText := s;
  for i := 0 to 2 do
    ix[i+1] := IndexOfPhaStr(sList[i]);
  if (ix[1] in [Ord(Low(p))..Ord(High(p))])
    then sobre.prj := pha(ix[1]);
  if (ix[2] in [Ord(Low(a))..Ord(High(a))])
    then sobre.arma := pha(ix[2]);
  if (ix[3] in [Ord(Low(h))..Ord(High(h))])
    then sobre.habt:= pha(ix[3]);
  sList.Free;
end;
```

If your text file contains more information, do a text conversion for them as well.

PS. I'll leave the error handling as an exercise.